# Handling onClick and onKeyPressDown in the same function React

Tags: reactjs, keypress, mouseclick-event

In React, I have a div that when clicked with a mouse, or tabbed and pressed enter or space upon, activates (it uses both onClick and onKeyPressDown to trigger the same function). However, I'm not sure how I can only account for mouse click events or enter/space events. For example, I don't want the function's setState call running if someone just hits a random key.

```
toggleFunction = () => {
     if (event.key === " " || event.key === "Enter") {
        this.setState({ this.state.pressed: !this.state.pressed })
     } 
}

<div onClick={this.toggleFunction} onKeyPressDown={this.toggleFunction}
```

In toggleFunction, how can I ensure that if a mouseclick occurs the state will change, but if a button that's not enter or space is pressed it does not change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use event.type to distinguish between different events like mouse/keyboard clicks

```
toggleFunction = (event) => {
     if (event.type === 'mousedown' || (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === " " || event.key === "Enter"))) {
        this.setState({ this.state.pressed: !this.state.pressed })
     } 
}
```